# Android not centering TextView's text vertically on device/emulator (but fine though in Android Studio's designer view)

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout, android-studio-2.0

I have this setup:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/postHeader">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CP"
            android:id="@+id/initialsView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/avatarView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/avatarView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/avatarView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/avatarView"
            android:background="@drawable/avatar_background"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
            app:riv_corner_radius="20dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/avatarView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            app:riv_border_color="@color/lightGray"
            app:riv_border_width="0.2dp" />

    ...
/>
```

The `TextView` aligns correctly to the image view. Everything is fine in Android Studio:

[image]

However, when I run on actual device (Android 4.4.4) or emulator (Android 6.0) I get the text ("CP" in the screenshot) stuck all the way to the top, just like I haven't set a vertical gravity. I've tried setting `textAlignment`, width and height to `match_parent`, `layout_centerInParent` to `both`, gravity to `center_vertical` explicity, `includeFontPadding` to false, but no avail. It still doesn't center vertically (horizontal is fine though).

What am I doing wrong? Why is it displayed correctly on Android Studio anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've figured out the problem after a bit investigation. Seems that it has been broken: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63673

Implementing the solution at the link solved my problem:

```
  private static final int AT_MOST_UNSPECIFIED = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((1<<30)-1, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec)
  {
    // RelativeLayout has bugs when measured in UNSPECIFIED height mode that were supposedly
    // fixed in API 18. However the 'fix' does breaks gravity == center_vertical in TextView. 
    // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63673
    if (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec) == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) heightSpec = AT_MOST_UNSPECIFIED;
    super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
  }
```